# Nested FOR loops are giving all permutations in one set. How would I split into two different associations?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, set

Lets say I have two dicts:

```
set1 = {"a":["description1", "description2"], "b":["description1", "description2"]}
set2 = {"c":["description1", "description2"], "d":["description1", "description2"]}
```

I am looping through them with nested loops and calling a function like this:

```
for key1, value1 in sorted(figure1.objects1.iteritems()):
    for key2, value2 in sorted(figure2.objects.iteritems()):
        self.compare_objects(figure1.objects[key1], figure2.objects[key2])
```

I end up with the

```
set = {"ac":"matching descriptors", "bd":"matching descriptors", "ad":"matching descriptors", "bc":"matching descriptors"}
```

I would like to have the associations separated:

```
set1 = {"ac":"matching descriptors", "bd":"matching descriptors"}
set2 = {"ad":"matching descriptors", "bc":"matching descriptors"}
```

This is because I am not sure which comparison is better and I need to check them against themselves.  This is a simple example.  Some of the later sets have 8 or more items each.

Please help, I find the loops and iterations confusing.

Comment: So how would the expected pairing look like for larger sets?

Comment: It sounds to me like you want to create a new "set" after the second for loop. If that is the case just split it up inline with the second loop and that should do the trick

Comment: Its n! combinations, so for this set of 2 there are four possible, for 3 there is six possible, 4 there is 24 possible.

Four the sets: [a b c ] to [d e f] you would get:
set1 {ad, bd, cf}, set2 {ae, bf, cd}, set3 {af, bd, ce}
set4 {ad, bf, ce}, set5 {ae, bd, cf}, set6 {af, be, cd}

Comment: Spelling...   For* the sets: